# Stuck filament in the extruder of Infitary M508

Tags: filament, extruder, motor, alunar-m508

**Model:** Infitary M508

**Details:** The filament is stuck in the extruder preheated for PLA (the filament is PLA 1.75 white). The extruder's motor works and the filament is in the hole of the extruder (not somewhere else). I took the fan covering the motor apart, to show what is inside, so you might see it on the attached image:

[image]

You might also see this video for details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8rYGhuYWvc

I'm able to pull the filament out, when I uncouple the motor's gear, but it doesn't go through the extruder when I push it in.

What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

P.S. It's the first start of the printer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you're going to have to tear the extruder head apart and clean the nozzle. There are kits like the following (found on Amazon - No affiliation):

[image]

This will give you everything you need to clear the nozzle. The only other solution is to replace the nozzle and extruder tube. The filament is stuck in either or both of these parts.

(As an aside ... a wise person < *cough* > @0scar < *cough* > once told me I should keep extras of these parts, as well as the thermister and heating elements on hand. Treat them as disposable parts ... once they're dead, just replace them.)

What you need to figure out though, is why it clogged in the first place. More than likely you tried to extrude filament before the nozzle was up to temperature. If your readout said it was good, then you need to get a no-touch thermometer and check the nozzle for the proper temperature prior to printing to ensure it's all good.

Comment: "Mind what you have learned. Save you it can." :)

Comment: Thanks, I've ordered a similar kit. Will try to clean first.

Comment: Cold extrusion won't give you a clog that needs fancy cleaning techniques -- get it up to proper operating temperature, and the clog will go away.

Comment: @Mark - It never hurts trying, but my experience with them is, once it's clogged, it won't unclog itself, even with heat.

Comment: Or perform a cold pull/atomic cleaning from e.g. [this answer](/a/6092). Used this last week after someone tried to print PLA at 250 ℃ on our Ultimaker 3E...

Answer (score 5):

The hot end can clog in two places.

1. Heat distortion can cause the filament above the nozzle, at the level of the cooling fins, to melt, expand and prevent further passage.
2. The nozzle itself may be clogged by impurities.

There are two methods available, depending on the type of clogging.

1. If the hot end is blocked at the level of the cooling fins, a so-called "Atomic Pull" helps. This is also a convenient method of changing filaments. The hot end is heated to approx. 90°C and the filament is pulled out of the hot end with a bold jerk. The filament does not melt completely and remains tough. Thus the complete plastic is pulled out of the hot end.
2. If the nozzle is clogged, an "Atomic Pull" only helps to a limited extent.
   To clean a nozzle, the hot end should be removed from the holder and the heating block unscrewed. You need a gas burner. With the gas burner the brass nozzle is heated until the plastic is completely carbonized. Wait until it has cooled down and reassemble the hotend.

Post-cleaning advice:
Be sure that the hotend is cooled enough that no heat can creep up the hotend and melt the plastic before it enters the heat block. Without sufficient cooling clogging pre-nozzle is very likely.